"Fatal error: Unable to allocate enough memory" but a lot of unused swap
I am trying to run CRABS (specifically the Pairwise Global Alignment subsection, which invokes vsearch)
on a 128GB RAM workstation, with OS=Ubuntu 23.04, kernel=6.2.0-39generic.
I have no problems running the analysis while reducing the maximum length of the sequences used as a reference, but I would like to use the complete reference database.
When I launch the script with the complete dataset, it fails at about 30% of the analysis  with the message:
Fatal error: Unable to allocate enough memory.
However the system has:

128GB RAM

776 GB swap


The swap is organized in a partition + 2 swapfiles (all on a NVME SSD).
NAME           TYPE      SIZE   USED PRIO
/swap.img      file        8G 339,4M   -2
/dev/nvme0n1p3 partition 256G     1G   -3
/home/swapfile file      512G     0B   -4

Swappiness is set to 60:
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
60

and the system correctly swaps when needed.
At about 30% of the analysis, with about 100% of the RAM and about 300GB of swap allocated, the analysis stops with the error above.
However, the system should have more than 400GB of swap still available.
I have already checked the CommitLimit (which is equal to the total memory available) and the Committed_AS at about the time of failure, but the last one is about 300GB (as shown by htop, too).
I have also set:
echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio

and also tried:
systemctl disable --now systemd-oomd
systemctl mask system-oomd

Anyone knows if any other system parameter/option may limit the usable swap size?
Thank you very much for you help.

Please [edit] your question and add the output of free -h . What is the command whose output you show there? Is it lsblk? Something else? And how large is your dataset? You mention amplicons so I am guessing your target regions aren't that large, but if you have several thousand x depth you could be dealing with a lot of data.

What you are doing with the memory overcommit and the OOMKiller probably has nothing to do with your problem and is dangerous. Did you check the ulimit settings?

Possibly because of hugepage usage (hugepage are not swappable). So check and tell us about it (  grep -i hugepages /proc/meminfo )
